# Are there alternate frameworks for unit testing xml other than xmlunit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Trying to see if there are any other frameworks out there that are similar to XmlUnit

Comment: What's wrong with XmlUnit?  If you tell us why you need an alternative...

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with it. The last release was sometime in 2009 and I am planning to use it heavily for my test automation. So i am wondering if there are any new frameworks that are in active development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://reflex.gforge.inria.fr/xunit.html

Answer (score 1):

[**Gallio/MbUnit v3**](http://gallio.org) has a couple of nice build-in assertions for testing XML. See that [article](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3axml_assertions) in the [Gallio Wiki](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=start) for more info.